# Use bootstrap .modal() on dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have my code here, that inserts a predefined modal markup at the end of the body:

```
var languageModal = 
'<div id="lngModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lngModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">'+
'   <div class="modal-body"></div>'+
'   <div class="modal-footer">'+
'       <form class="inline" id="lngModalForm">'+
'           <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">'+
'               <span lang="hu"'+((langAfterInit == 'hu') ? '' : ' style="display:none;"')+'>Bezárás</span>'+
'               <span lang="en"'+((langAfterInit != 'hu') ? ' style="display:none;"' : '')+'>Close</span>'+
'           </button>'+
'       </form>'+
'   </div>'+
'</div>';

$('body').append(languageModal);
```

But, when I call `.modal()` on it, it won't load, only the black overlay appears:

```
$('#lngModal').modal({
    backdrop    : 'static',
    keyboard    : false,
    remote      : '/language.html',
});
```

I tried with `.on('modal',{...})`, but that didn't work.

Comment: sure you loaded the modal.js ? also, are you trying opening automatically the modal or opening that on btn click or somenthing like this?

Comment: @Badaboooooom Allow me to share the js file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/osgkfcmqtm4p42v/init.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of help from @**Badaboooooom** and @**ic3b3rg**, turns out I had to exchange the `.modal({... remote : '...', ..})` for a `data-remote="..."` tag in the script markup, and also had to remove the `.fade` from `#lngModal`.

```
var languageModal =  '<div id="lngModal" class="modal hide"  data-remote="/language.html">'+
//other stuff

$('#lngModal').modal('show',{
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: false,
});
```

Comment: why does data-remote solve this and where does /language.html come from

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $('body').append(languageModal,function(){
console.log('modal appended');
    $('#lngModal').modal({
                    backdrop    : 'static',
                    keyboard    : false,
                    remote      : '/language.html',
                }); 

console.log('modal init');
    });
```

instead of

```
$('body').append(languageModal);
            $('#lngModal').modal({
                backdrop    : 'static',
                keyboard    : false,
                remote      : '/language.html',
            });
```

Comment: Now my site won't get past the append script, it gets stuck, but I get no console errors. The [file I posted](https://www.dropbox.com/s/osgkfcmqtm4p42v/init.js) updates live so you can see what I changed.

Comment: uhm ... so strange can you alert your modal html? it shows you the modal? then can you create a jsfiddle.net so i can help you deeply?

Comment: I'll upload my site to ftp and give you a link, wait.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22001/discussion-between-badaboooooom-and-djdavid98)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work. Are you loading the bootstrap css?

http://jsfiddle.net/xjCAn/

I can't post this w/o some code:

```
' Nothing, really
```

Comment: You forgot `remote: '/language.html'`, I'm guessing that's why it works.

Comment: I omitted it since it won't be found

Comment: Join us @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22001/discussion-between-badaboooooom-and-djdavid98

Answer (score 0):

I had that also once, but only when I wanted to increase to modal size by using the following css:

```
var modal = $('#lngModal');
modal.css({
   width: '60%',
   left: '20%',
   margin: 'auto auto auto auto',
   top: '10%'
});
```

I fixed it by setting `max-height` on the `modal-body`:

```
var modalBody = modal.children('.modal-body');

modalBody.css({
   maxHeight: '800px'
});
```

Did you change the modal css?

Comment: Yes, `.modal *, .modal input, .alert {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}`, `.modal > h4 { padding-bottom:7px }`, `.modal-body { padding-bottom:0 }`

Comment: why you repeat Helvetica Neue i think bootstrap uses itself

Comment: @Badaboooooom My site uses a different main font, I customized it.